# Lua - get table to C, update it and upload it back

Tags: c, lua

I have Lua table with undefined structure (eg. user can put there anything - number, string etc). I need to get the data table into C code, store it in data file and then some time later open it and restore values into Lua script.

`lua_topointer` get me data adress, but thats about all. There is no way how to get data from it and to upload it back.

How to do this ?

Comment: is that all you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't be better to serialize data on Lua side in string. (yep, you will loose unserializable data like functions or userdata). Then you can save that string to file, and unserialize later.

If you want to do that on C side, you should traverse over your table. You get only reference to it. It's a lot of error - prone, boilerplate code, and you hardly will get any performance benefit form it.

Look at http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization for ready-to use Lua serialization code.

Comment: You can certainly recognize, encode and later restore references to known values which should not/can not be serialized.

Comment: It will work but not always. My file can be stored on network and Lua has no access to it (or some ftp).

Comment: @Deduplicator Data may be unserialized in other environment. In that cases, you couldn't believe in stored references, as them didn't exists.

Comment: @Seagull: I never said you should encode them as raw pointers or some such. Use proper symbols denoting them, which must be mapped back on the receiving side.